# Having an issue with array keys, undefined index

Tags: php, arrays

I'm working with a couple of arrays, one of which has keys that are the productid, the value being an object that contains a doctrine entity of that product. Similarly, I have a plan with the index being the plan Id. For this for loop, I need to go through and individually set up invoices for each plan-product pair (the quantity will always be the same between them, except in cases where a user is purchasing a plan for an already owned device). Obviously this is somewhat complicated, so I'm not exactly sure how to phrase this question. An error occurs at the commented line, "Notice: Undefined Index"

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalInvoices; $i++) {
        if ($i == $planQuantity[key($plans)]) {
            next($plans);
        }
        if ($i == $productQuantity[key($products)]) {
            next($products);
        }
        $data = array(
            'planId' => key($plans),
//below here, I'm thinking at key($products) is where the error occurs
            'productId' => key($products) != 0 ? key($products) : $plans[key($plans)]->getPricingTier()->getProductId(),
            'userId' => $this->userId,
            'paymentMethodId' => $paymentMethodId
        );
        if ($order['hasProduct'] || isset($order['activating'])) {
            if (!isset($order['activating'])) {
                $planModel->createDevicePlan($data);
                $productAmount = $products[key($products)]->getAmount();
            } else {
                $data['deviceId'] = $order['activating']['inventoryId'];
                $planModel->createDevicePlan($data, date('Y-m-d'));
                $productAmount = 0;
            }
        } else {
            $productAmount = 0;
        }
        if ($iteration % 5 == 0 && $order['hasShipping']) {
            $invoiceShippingAmount = $billingModel->getShippingAmount($shippingOptionsId);
        } else {
            $invoiceShippingAmount = 0;
        }
        $salesData = array(
            'paymentMethodsId'    => $paymentMethodId,
            'planAmount'          => $plans[key($plans)]->getAmount(),
            'planId'              => key($plans),
            'productAmount'       => $productAmount,
            'productId'           => key($products),
            'shippingAddressesId' => $shippingAddressId,
            'shippingAmount'      => $invoiceShippingAmount,
            'shippingOptionsId'   => $shippingOptionsId,
            'transactionId'       => $transactionId,
            'userId'              => $this->userId
        );
        $iteration++;
        $billingModel->createInvoice($salesData);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused about the role of the `$planQuantity` and `$productQuantity` arrays

Comment: planQuantity has an index with a planid and then the number of plans to iterate through, productQuantity is the same but with productId as index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment reply, I think this will help

```
$plans_on_invoice = 0;
$products_on_invoice = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < $totalInvoices; $i++) {
    next($plans);
    if ($plans_on_invoice == 0) {
        $plans_on_invoice = $planQuantity[key($plans)];
    }
    plans_on_invoice--;
    next($products);
    if ($products_on_invoice == 0) {
        $products_on_invoice = $productQuantity[key($products)];
    }
    products_on_invoice--;
```

Comment: Unless I'm missing something that was implied, that's not working either. :(

Comment: I think we're both on different wavelengths here. I'm guessing as to what `$planQuantity` and `$productQuantity` really is. I think there's a structural issue with the code, and not just syntax.

Comment: I can post the whole method if that would help

Comment: Fixed by adding hasNext method and calling that.
    private function hasNext($array)
    {
        if (is_array($array)) {
            if (next($array) === false) {
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

Don't know why that worked but checking the array size first doesn't.

Comment: And what do you do if that returns false? Break out of your loop?